# How to change style of radio button / checkbox in Kony Visualizer? (Responsive Web)

Tags: css, visualizer, temenos-quantum

Is it possible to change the style of the radio button/checkbox in Kony Visualizer? (Responsive Web)

can we can pseudo-classes in custom CSS (Kony visualizer)?